# How to use CABasicAnimation to move from point to another point?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, caanimation

I'm using `CABasicAnimation` to perform an animation move object from point to point in my application but after animation finish moving to destination point, it always display at start point. How to prevent it won't display at start point after finish animation?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot to set actual finishing point value to your object. With `CABasicAnimation` you add your animation **AND** set property accordingly.

Comment: Here my code: CABasicAnimation *translateAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
    translateAnim.duration = 1.0;
    translateAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    translateAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-100.f];
    [layer addAnimation:translateAnim forKey:@"move"];

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
CGRect frame=objectName.frame;
frame.origin.x=frame.origin.x-20;//change the point according to you
frame.origin.y=frame.origin.y-20;//change the point according to you
objectName.frame=frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: This code works fine, but I actually want to use Core Animation to perform an complex animation. For example, move object on path which define by user.

Comment: so that you have to change the position of object after animation so that whenever your animation finished you object remain to the destination point